# PHP Contact Form Submission (Honey Pot)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

New to PHP hence the very basic question. I'm trying to create a contact form that has a Honey Pot attribute built in. I want to check this honey pot value in both JS and PHP before submission.

Cases:

- If no fields are filled out JS error don't Submit
- If all fields are filled out BUT Honey Pot, Pass through JS, POST to PHP and send email
- If all fields are filled out fail on JS and don't POST, HOWEVER I would like this to also be applicable to the PHP even if it's redundant just to understand PHP better.

Problem:

The JS validation is fine and I check `.val` of the input field. However I cannot seem to get the same validation in PHP to work.

**index.html (contact form) *using jQuery Validate:**

```
<form id="contactForm" method="GET" action="" class="contact-form" novalidate="novalidate">
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <input name="name" type="text" id="name" class="validate" required/>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <input name="email" type="text" id="email" class="validate" required/>
    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <textarea name="message" id="message" class="materialize-textarea" required></textarea>
    <label>Message</label>
   </div>
   <div class="input-field comment col s12">
     <label>If you're human leave this blank:</label>
     <input name="comment" type="text" id="comment" class="form-comment" />
   </div>
   <div class="col s12">
     <button class="btn button-primary contact-submit-button waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Send</button>
   </div>
   <div id="form-result"></div>
 </form>
```

**contact-form.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var contactFormResult = $('#form-result');
  var contactForm = $('#contactForm');
  contactFormResult.hide();
  $.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function () {
      var nameValue = $('#name').val();
      var emailValue = $('#email').val();
      var messageValue = $('#message').val();
      var robotValue = $('#comment').val();
      console.log('contact form submission, name value: ' + nameValue, ' email value: ' + emailValue + ' message value: ' + messageValue + ' robot value: ' + robotValue);

      // 
      // I want this to pass through JS and FAIL in PHP
      //
      if (robotValue = ''){
        contactFormResult.text('you are a robot').fadeIn();
        return false;
      } else {
         $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "contactSubmission.php",
          data: {
            name: nameValue,
            email: emailValue,
            message: messageValue,
            robotTest: robotValue
          }
        }).done(function () {
          contactForm.find("input[type=text], input[type=email], textarea").val("");
          contactFormResult.text('form submitted successfully').fadeIn();
        });
      }
    }
  });
  contactForm.validate();
});
```

**contactSubmission.php**

```
<?php
if ($_POST){
    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $nameValue = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $emailValue = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $messageValue = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $robotValue = filter_var($_POST["robotTest"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if(!empty($robotValue){
        die();
    } else {
        $to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
        $subject = 'Subject Line';

        $message = 'Name: ' .$nameValue. ' Email: ' .$emailValue.' Message: '.$messageValue;

        mail($to, $subject, $message);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your form is using a GET method, yet you're using POST arrays and I don't see a name attribute matching `robotTest`.

Comment: The `POST` is happening in the `AJAX` request so I don't have to refresh the page. I want the user to stay at the bottom of the page and then do AJAX request send off those values into the PHP file. `data.robotTest` contains the string that is passed into the submission file.

Comment: look at your console then and use error reporting, see if anything comes of it

Comment: Plus, if and when they disable JS, your GET method in the form won't work for the POST arrays, so keep that in mind also.

Comment: Using Xdbug helper and Chrome Logger for PHP. None seem to be doing anything. I've added a simple `<?php echo "hello there from contact submission"; ...` at the top of the page so when it fires would hopefully see something. But that isn't working either. SO is there another method to use the console and to combat disabled JS can just run a `<noscript>` prompting user to enable for submission as JS in most cases shouldn't be disabled.

This PHP does work when not trying to use conditionals. So what is the problem here with validating an empty value?

Comment: you have a logical problem in your _JS_. in this line `if (robotValue = ''){` you are trying to bypass the _JS_ checking and you are setting the value of `x` to _empty_ . So what ever you type in the comments, because of this line, your `php` will receive an empty value for the `robotTest` varibale...

Comment: @EhsanT How is `var robotValue` getting reset when it's just checking the value in the conditional? `var robotValue = $('#comment').val();` is being set how can `if (robotValue = ''){...}` reset that value?

Comment: in _JavaScript if statement_ you have to use 2 = signs for comparison. if you use 1, it will set the value of the left side variable to the right side value of the = sign. so the correct term will be `if (robotValue == ''){`